# JavaScript função

Tags: javascript, funções

Tenho esse seguinte exercício de função em JavaScript aqui:

> Faça uma função que recebe a idade de uma pessoa em anos, meses e dias e retorna essa idade expressa em dias.

Ele consegue receber a idade em anos e expressar em dias, mas não consegue ler em meses e tbm em dias. Alguma sugestão?

```js
var idade = Number.parseInt(prompt("Digite sua idade"));

document.write("Sua idade é: " + idade);
document.write("A sua idade em dias é: " + idadeEmDias(idade));

function idadeEmDias(anos, meses, dias) {
  return anos * 365;

}
```

Comment: Como seria feita essa entrada *em anos, meses e dias*?

Comment: Para calcular a idade total em dias acho que seria essa expressão `return anos * 365 + meses * 30 + dias;`

Comment: Tem o detalhe de que Fevereiro tem 28 ou 29 dias, se é um ano bissexto! pode complementar usando objeto `Date` para ter uma exatidão maior em relação aos dias

Comment: Como foi mencionado  *...idade de uma pessoa em anos, meses e dias ...*   a entrada
pede _dias em anos_  ou do _primeiro dia do ano até agora_  ?

Answer (score -2):

Primeiro teria que entender se iria ser considerado os anos bissextos.

mas considerando que utilizar uma expressão simples como "(anos * 365) + (meses * 30) + dias" teria sempre um resultado duvidoso.

Recomendo ler sobre a [class Date do javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

utilizando a classe Date você pode subitrair a idade passada da data atual e posteriormente pegar a diferença de tempo e dividir por a fração de tempo que representa um dia

```js
function calculaDias(anos, meses, dias) {
  let hoje = new Date()

  // pegando a data de nascimento
  let nacsimento = new Date() // cria um objeto de data com a data atual
  nacsimento.setFullYear(nacsimento.getFullYear() - anos) // subtrai os anos da data atual
  nacsimento.setMonth(nacsimento.getMonth() - meses) // subtrai os meses da data atual
  nacsimento.setDate(nacsimento.getDate() - dias) // subtrai os dias da data atual

  // calculando a diferença entre as datas em milissegundos
  let diferencaMs = hoje.getTime() - nacsimento.getTime()
  let totalDias = diferencaMs / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)
  return Math.floor(totalDias)
}

const anos = 25
const meses = 2
const dias = 20

console.log(calculaDias(anos, meses, dias))
```